# How to improve Undertow websocket performance with constant small writes?

Tags: java, performance, websocket, nio, undertow

I have an existing, stable, working software project which currently uses Tyrus for the websocket client side, and Undertow 2.2.2 (Wildfly) for the server side.  I'm able to get about 90% of the maximum connection speed when using these respective libraries, which is plenty fast for my needs.

The problem occurred when switching the client to **also** use Undertow. I was forced to modify my ByteBuffers to be much larger in size to compensate for the increased overhead that Undertow websockets have compared to Tyrus. Without modification, my throughput was dropping to about 30%.

Is there any way to tune Undertow to not perform slowly when sending small frequent ByteBuffers?

**Technical details**: *ByteBuffer size was about 256 bytes with Tyrus. Had to increase to 4096 for Undertow to match performance. Throughput at full speed is about 10 MB/s on my current hardware.*

Comment: Undertow 3.0 now uses Netty - I'd be interested if you're still having this issue with Netty https://undertow.io/blog/2019/04/15/Undertow-3.html

Comment: Thank you for the tip @Charlie - I'll have to take a look.  I've moved to using WildFly bootable, but I imagine they'll also be adopting Undertow 3.0

Comment: fyi I just benchmarked Undertow 3.0 vs Vert.x and was disappointed in Undertow - Vert.x was much faster. I was actually comparing Quarkus which uses Undertow to Vert.x to see which was faster.

Comment: @Charlie You mean you tested an older version of Quarkus which used Undertow and then a newer Quarkus which is based on Vert.x ?

Comment: I went back and doubled checked and found out that Quarkus actually runs Undertow on top of Vert.x so it's not the same as your typical Undertow 3.0. As a result I have no idea how fast Undertow 3.0 is only that whatever Quarkus did is much slower than pure Vert.x in my tests. https://quarkus.io/guides/websockets